# Acessing other py file's class

Tags: python

I have two files:
a.py
b.py

How can I access my ABC123 class defined in a.py from b.py?

Comment: Why Python tutorial are you using?  I ask because this is rather fundamental.  So your tutorial must be either incomplete or misleading.  Which tutorial are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import a
x = a.ABC123()
```

or

```
from a import ABC123
x = ABC123()
```

will do the job, as long as `a.py` and `b.py` are in the same directory, or if `a.py` is in a directory in `sys.path` or in a directory in your environment's `$PYTHONPATH`.  If neither of those is the case, you might want to read up on relative imports in [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

In spite of being several years old, [*Importing Python Modules*](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) might be worth reading for a more thorough overview of importing from other modules.  It does seem beginner-friendly, too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the objects from the other file:

```
from a import ABC123
```

For a good discussion on this topic please see [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm):

> The import and from-import statements
>   are a constant cause of serious
>   confusion for newcomers to Python.
>   Luckily, once you’ve figured out what
>   they really do, you’ll never have
>   problems with them again.
>
> This note tries to sort out some of
>   the more common issues related to
>   import and from-import and everything.